# About R12 corruption in Arm compiler

Tags: compiler-construction

The __aeabi_memcpy(standard lib) function provided by arm compiler 6 use r12 as a intermediate variable.

As i know, r12 is not preserved by caller or callee.

If a caller uses r12 for some purpose before __aeabi_memcpy,then r12 will be corrupted after __aeabi_memcpy.

Is it right? Or compiler will do something to prevent?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the usecase of Scratch Registers in ARM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62840714/what-is-the-usecase-of-scratch-registers-in-arm)

Comment: r12 must be saved by the caller if its value needs to be preserved across the call.

Comment: So the compiler will preserve r12? No decument describe it