# How to know the details of arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc's implementation of aapcs

Tags: c, gcc, arm, abi

I've read the parts `"6 The Base Procedure Call Standard"` and `"7 The Standard Variants"` of *Procedure Call Standard for the Arm® Architecture*    [aapcs32 - Github](https://github.com/ARM-software/abi-aa/blob/844a79fd4c77252a11342709e3b27b2c9f590cf1/aapcs32/aapcs32.rst#the-base-procedure-call-standard)

The Base Procedure Call Standard specifies that `r0-r3` in processor can be used to pass parameters. And the Standard Variants introduced in part 7 specifies `s0-s15` in VFP-v2 co-processor can be used to do so.
However, I cannot find aapcs specifying the reflection between arguments list in C and parameters passing registers. What else, the sequence for stacking arguments is unspecified.

So how can I know the implementation defined behaviour by `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc`?

Comment: https://github.com/ARM-software/abi-aa/blob/2982a9f3b512a5bfdc9e3fea5d3b298f9165c36b/aapcs64/aapcs64.rst

Comment: The AAPCS is an extension of the APCS.  If you can not find something in that section, assume it is the same for the 'Advanced' version.  I had to read your question many times to try and discern what you are asking.  Note: that options to `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc` can affect some register use.  Such as `-msingle-pic-base` and possibly others (`-mabi=name`).

Comment: A more difficult question with AAPCS is how to create the winding/unwinding information in assembler.  With APCS, everything was dependant on the frame pointer.  However, if you custom code assembler to inter-operate with GCC, you may need to add unwind information for applications with signals, etc.  See: https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.21/as/ARM-Directives.html

Comment: `int foo(int a, int b, int c, int d)`.  `a` is in R0, `b` is in R1, `c` is in R2, `d` is in R3.  The URL you reference had all information, but that.  If your question is something else, it is in the URL references.  R4-R8 are consistent.  Above R8, compiler/system options can affect register use.  Mainly for shared libraries, PIC code, and other issues.

Comment: This question may interest you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45359408/r12-in-the-arm-procedure-call-standard

Comment: @artlessnoise Thanks a lot! That's very helpful! Maybe I didn't phase it very clearly because English is not my native language. The example `int foo(...)`  you give is intuitive. But it may be a litttle bit more complex considering `int foo(float a,int b,int c,int d,long long e,double f)` with option `-mfloat-abi=hard`. I feel confused since I cannot find the mentions about a arguments list in C language mixed int and float data types in the document.

Comment: You can look at the documentation or run an [example on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/7aK941Exa).  We can see that 'b' is place in R0 and 'a' is in 's0'.  So (for hard float-abi), the arguments are pass in s0.. and r0... and assigned by type.  The 'gnueabihf' is as per [ARM float-abi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321468/whats-the-difference-between-hard-and-soft-floating-point-numbers/29705738#29705738).