# I cant get my thread context switching code to work (ARM procesor)

Tags: c, arm, embedded, stm32, cortex-m

Im developing a "operating system" on ARM. My context switching code for swapping between tasks is not working.

I have a function demo() which I am calling in main. In this I am creating a "fake context" for my task, consisting of 16 empty register values which will be swapped into the cpu registers when I load the task. Once I do so, I call a supervisor call which enters the PendSV handler, and in this handler i have the assembler code for loading/unloading registers. The printertask() will repeatedly load itself and deload itself by calling the PendSV code.

My code is able to Load the printertask() task context and run it once, but it has trouble loading it back after saving it. I suspect something is going wrong during the saving process.
The program hardfaults currently after trying to load the program after it ran once

```
void printertask() {
    printf("Printing some text here\r\n");

    __set_PSP(THREAD_SPACE_START); // set PSP to the top of the stack location

    __asm("SVC #10"); // My custom SVC which redirects to PendSV
}


void switchTest() {
    printf("Switch test, TSP %p %ld\r\n", THREAD_SPACE_START, *THREAD_SPACE_START);
    __set_PSP(THREAD_SPACE_START - 15); // set psp to stack head
}


// stack grows down from MSP Init val
void demo() {
    uint32_t* MSP_INIT_VAL = *(uint32_t**)0x0;
    THREAD_SPACE_START = (uint32_t)MSP_INIT_VAL - MAIN_STACK_SIZE;

    // make fake context and set psp
    uint32_t* stack_ptr = THREAD_SPACE_START;
    *(stack_ptr) = 1 << 24;
    *(--stack_ptr) = (uint32_t)printertask;
    for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++)
    {
        *(--stack_ptr) = 0xA;
    }
    __set_PSP(stack_ptr - 17); // set psp to some garbage value for deloading stack into

    // examine
    stack_ptr = THREAD_SPACE_START;
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        printf("%p: %ld\r\n", stack_ptr, *stack_ptr);
        stack_ptr--;
    }

    // deload registers, load fake context, then run task
    __asm("SVC #3");

}
```

[image]

Logs:

```
BEGIN
(these next lines show the fake register values as loaded into memory from demo())
0x20017c00: 16777216
0x20017bfc: 134219281 (start of printer function in instruction memory)
0x20017bf8: 10 (0xA)
0x20017bf4: 10
0x20017bf0: 10
0x20017bec: 10
0x20017be8: 10
0x20017be4: 10
0x20017be0: 10
0x20017bdc: 10
0x20017bd8: 10
0x20017bd4: 10
0x20017bd0: 10
0x20017bcc: 10
0x20017bc8: 10
0x20017bc4: 10
svc_number 3
Switch test, TSP 0x20017c00 16777216
Printer
svc_number 3
Switch test, TSP 0x20017c00 10
(hardfaults here)
```

Is this a problem with my understanding of LDMIA? I have a -15 offset so it starts loading from the bottom of the task stack in memory (or at least thats what im trying to do). From my understanding the BX LR to the magic number will restore the 8 saved special registers. In the switchTest() log it seems that PSP is set properly to the top of the stack on the second load and the value matches. So i think it is a problem with my command usage somehow.

Comment: It seems a very complex question to answer.  You use (post as an image) `stmdb r0!,r4-r11` which will update the PSP value in r0, and then use `ldmia r0!,r4-r11` which uses the `r0` which `switchTest()` is bound to set . This is a great [use case for `ip`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45359408/r12-in-the-arm-procedure-call-standard).  Ie, use `ip` instead of R0 and be sure to put `ip` in r4-r11 (or you can update PSP).  Then you can use the `r4-r11` register in the restore which the ABI says `switchTest()` should preserve.

Comment: So, I believe the issue is the 'C' to assembler interface and a conflict in register use.  These questions on [ARM link and frame pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15752188/arm-link-register-and-frame-pointer), [ARM calling convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261419/what-registers-to-save-in-the-arm-c-calling-convention), and older [APCS](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~fms27/teaching/2001-02/arm-project/02-sort/apcs.txt) and AAPCS documents may help you.

Comment: You should first simplify the program. Context switch is not so hard, but your code is a mess. You can start with creating a ThreadContext struct with 17 uint32_t R0...LR, PC, xPSR, so you can easily save and recover them via fixed offset in assembly. Also remember there exist naked functions which remove function prologue and epilogue and are perfect for inline assembly. You can call other functions from assembly, return value would be in R0. Imo, you can't fix your program because it looks like barely debuggable mess (saying it as someone who implemented context switch using inline assembly)